# Tasks that only check values in registered variable

Tags: ansible

I'd like to use Ansible tasks to check for the presence of a string in a registered variabe.

I'm trying to use one task to fetch a process' command-line arguments using `ps` and register it as `command_line`.

I'd then like to have several tasks that are simply checking for the presence of a string in `command_line`.

I tried this:

```
- name: Get command line args
  raw: ps aux | grep "binary" | grep -v grep
  register: command_line
  changed_when: False

- name: Check --hello-world flag passed
  failed_when: "'--hello-world' not in command_line.stdout"
```

This doesn't work because there is no action in the the second task. It throws an error.

NB: There is no Python on the servers, so I can't use most Ansible actions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the condition below

```
when: command_line.stdout is not search('--hello-world')
```